# Handle click event inside {#each} block in svelte

Tags: event-handling, svelte, svelte-3

I am a svelte beginner and i have a problem with event handlers inside the each block.
In the Repl when i click shuffle multiple times, i have multiple event listener for the heart inside the card. The click event on the card works fine and has only one event listener.
How can i prevent to have multiple event listeners on the heart?

[Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/8bc7ac08f5b24ff3bb4eb55cf7975a53?version=3.20.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove they key, that way the items are re-created, and the event handlers aren't sticking around.

`{#each dataShow as d (d.poi)}` => `{#each dataShow as d}`